# How to loop over the arguments in a list with specified ranges in python?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, loops

Let say we have given this little program:

```
a = [[70, 19, 54,  7, 63],
     [78, 72, 93, 78, 33],
     [83, 55, 57,  9, 22],
     [95, 64, 90, 91, 54]]

for x, y, *z in a:
    print("x = {}, y = {}, z = {}".format(x, y, z))
```

This will give me for the first element in the list `a`:

```
x = 70, y = 19, z = [54, 7, 63]
```

But what I want is to define, how many elements the defined variable should have, e.g. something like this:

```
for x, y[:2], z[:2] in a:
    print("x = {}, y = {}, z = {}".format(x, y, z))
```

Its true that this will not work in python. (I have tried it out)

It would be nice if there is a way to do something like this in python.

I know that I could do something like this:

```
b = list(zip(*a))

c1 = b[0]
c2 = list(zip(*b[1:3]))
c3 = list(zip(*b[3:5]))

for x, y, z in zip(c1, c2, c3):
    print("x = {}, y = {}, z = {}".format(x, y, z))
```

Which would give me for the first argument in `a`:

```
x = 70, y = (19, 54), z = (7, 63)
```

But for a huge list `a` this is now so very efficient.

Comment: So why not just assign from slices *in the loop*? `for values in a: x, y, z = values[0], values[1:3], values[3:5]`.

Comment: or better still, use a more detailed data structure that doesn't put all the values into one long list.

Comment: That would work, but I thought that it would be possible to do it directly in the for loop.

Comment: @PiMathCLanguage: you could do that with `for x, y, z in (v[0],v[1:3],v[3:5] for v in a):`.

Comment: Not with unpacking assignments, no, you get just the one wildcard. It's use-case is not to let you assign arbitrary-length sub-lists however, it is to help deal with ignoring extraneous entries.

Comment: In the for loop iterable, you can add a generator expression, but that can be rather unreadable.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Could you give me an example with a generator as a response to my question? So I can accept it as my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` operator in assignments is intended to be used to capture 'extrenous' elements of a list. It is not intended to be a pattern matching language.

Your options are:

- Generate more structured data. If your input was already grouped into tuples or other objects, you'd have an easier time handling it in a loop.
- Extract the sub-lists in the loop, then assign:

  ```
  for values in a:
      x, y, z = values[0], values[1:3], values[3:5]
  ```
- Use a generator expression to repack the structures; looping over a generator expression takes place in parallel to iteration over the generator:

  ```
  a_repacked = ((v[0], v[1:3], v[3:5]) for v in a)
  for x, y, z in a_repacked:
      # ...
  ```

  You can inline the generator expression into the `for` loop statement, but for readability I recommend you stick to a separate variable.